# Spring @Value with arraylist split and obtain the first value

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-el

Spring `@Value` with arraylist split and get the first value of arrayList

I had `my.list=a,b,c`
I am struggling to get the first value i.e., a

I tried,

```
@Value("#{'${my.list}'.split(',')})
List<String> values;
String myVal = values.get(0);
```

Is there any better method than this procedure?

Comment: @Value("#{'${my.list}'.split(',')})
 List<String> values; 
String myVal = values.get(0);

here every statement is in new line. Unfortunately here it is displaying continuously

Comment: and why would you have something like this?

Comment: Have you tried `@Value("#{'${my.list}'.split(',')[0]})` or a combination should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U have a syntax error in this line

```
@Value("#{'${my.list}'.split(',')})
```

That should be corrected as below

```
@Value("#{'${my.list}'.split(',')}")
List<String> values;
```

I would suggest you below solution as a better method

A domain class

```
@Component
public class Data {


    @Value("#{'${my.list}'.split(',')}")
    List<String> values;



    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

}
```

This how you can use the domain class

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
public class Mycon {


    @Autowired
    Data data;

    @GetMapping
    public String hello(ModelMap model) {

        return data.getValues().get(0);

    }

}
```

application.properties file

```
my.list=a,b,c
```

You can take that value directly as below

```
@Value("#{'${my.list}'.split(',')[0]}")
String values;
```

Comment: can you help me with just @Value(<exp>)  statement so that I directly get the value 'a'

Comment: @Prathyusha Yes i can help .You can refer to the edited answer as per your request.

Comment: @Prathyusha . You are welcome . You can mark the answer as a correct answer to be refered by others as a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
Environment env;

//To get the List<String>
List<String> values = Arrays.asList(env.getProperty("my.list").split(",");

//Then, you can get value into an Optional to prevent NullPointerException
Optional<String> myValue = values.stream().findFirst();
```

Comment: can you help me with just @Value(<exp>)  statement so that I directly get the value 'a' .