# Mapping an array of properties in spring boot and injecting into a prototype scope

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am very new to spring boot and here is how my yaml looks like

```
configs:
    - 
      collection: col1
      groupId: groupId1
      topic: topic1
    - 
      collection: col2
      groupId: groupId2
      topic: topic2
```

I would like to have 3 classes with their scope defined as a prototype and use the property from the yaml something like

```
@Scope(value = ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class mongoListener {


    public mongoListener(@Value("${config.collection}") String collectionName) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Similarly, have 2 more classes that would use groupID and topic as well. I am stuck here on how to design.

It will be of great help if anyone can explain how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

- Put your `application.yaml` that consists of your yaml configuration into `/src/main/resources/`.
- Use the property by `@Value` annotation like:

```
public mongoListener(@Value("${configs[0].collection}") String collectionName) {
    // collectionName is 'col1'
    //do something
}
```

**[EDIT 1]**

You can create `singleton` beans different from each other in name like:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean("mongoListener_A")
    public mongoListener mongoListener_A(@Value("${configs[0].collection}") String collectionName) {
        return new mongoListener(collectionName);
    }

    @Bean("mongoListener_B")
    public mongoListener mongoListener_B(@Value("${configs[1].collection}") String collectionName) {
        return new mongoListener(collectionName);
    }

    // ... and so on
}
```

**[EDIT 2]**

You can read your yaml configurations into java objects by using `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation.

```
@Data //lombok annotation.
@Component("myConfigs")
@ConfigurationProperties
public class Configs {

    private final List<Config> configs;

    @Data //lombok annotation.
    public static class Config {

        private String collection;
        private String groupId;
        private String topic;

    }
}
```

You can create your `mongoListener`s from that objects like:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public List<mongoListener> mongoListeners(@Qualifier("myConfigs") Configs configs) {
        return configs.getConfigs().stream()
                .map(Config::getCollection)
                .map(mongoListener::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    // ... and so on
}
```

The beans are still `singleton` but you can create an arbitrary number of instances depending on your yaml file.

**See Also**
[Use YAML for External Properties - Spring Boot Reference Documentation “How-to” Guides](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-use-yaml-for-external-properties)
[Spring @Value with arraylist split and obtain the first value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56454902/spring-value-with-arraylist-split-and-obtain-the-first-value)

Comment: Thanks, But, I would like to have two instances of MongoListener one for each collection and this was the reason for making the bean as  "prototype".

Comment: I think you can create `singleton` beans different from each other in name. So I added '[EDIT 1]'. Can it meet your requirements?

Comment: No, Actually, I would like to have this created dynamically. I wouldn't know the number of collections etc before hand.

Comment: If you want to create a list of the objects(e.g. `List<mongoListener>`) depending on your yaml file(dynamically),  `@ConfigurationProperties` annotation is useful. Your beans are still `singleton` but you can create arbitrary number of objects. Does it satisfy your requirements? (I added '[EDIT 2]')